# jQuery datepicker - code won't work?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker

New to jQuery. I cannot get the datepicker to work. Can anyone tell my what I am doing wrong? Thank you, any help is appreciated. Here is the skeleton code:

```html
<html>
 <head>
  <title>Example</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <script>
   $(function() {
    $("#quoteDate").datepicker();
   });
  </script>
 </head>
 <body>
  <input type="text" id="quoteDate">
 </body>
</html>
```

I have looked at many posts almost identical to this one, but none of the answers worked. I have also downloaded the jQuery UI files to reference them locally, but that wouldn't work either.

Comment: Your code works. Hit Run code and check yourself

Comment: what browser are you using? seems to be working in the snippet

Comment: in your example it works there is nothing wrong with it.

Comment: Working for me as well.

Comment: It works, what doesnt works for you?

Comment: I notice it runs on this site, but it's not working on my computer for some reason. Won't work in Chrome or Firefox or IE. Strange

Comment: It works fine : http://jsfiddle.net/j8h4qo6y/ Destroy your computer and buy a new one

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They aren't working for you locally because you are running them from a file with a url like `file:///Macintosh HD/whatever...`.

You need to change the lines:

```
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```

to:

```
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```

When you use a `//` prefix for an asset, it matches whatever protocol you are using. So when you load up something locally (without using a local web server), it looks for `file:///code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js` which doesn't exist. Changes the assets to start with `http://` or `https://` instead of `//`.

Comment: He said also:  `I have also downloaded the jQuery UI files to reference them locally, but that wouldn't work either.`

Comment: Ah yes that's fixed it. I don't know why I couldn't reference them locally then

Comment: Did you changed the href to : `jquery-1.10.2.js` ?

Answer (score 1):

After reading the above answers and your comments, it seems that you are unable to run it locally on your browser.

**Referencing Files Locally**
Easiest way is to download and keep all the files in same directory.
Let's say the files are
`index.htm`, `jquery-ui.css`, `jquery-1.10.2.js`, `jquery-ui.js`

File : `index.htm`

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Example</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="jquery-ui.css">
    <script src="jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
    <script src="jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(function() {
            $("#quoteDate").datepicker();
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <input type="text" id="quoteDate">
</body>
</html>
```

**Relative Path**
You can give relative path such as
`src="js/jquery-1.10.2.js"`
`src="js/jquery-ui.js"`
`href="css/jquery-ui.css"`
 if the directory structure is :

```
Present Working Directory
    index.htm
    js (directory)
        jquery-1.10.2.js
        jquery-ui.js
    css (directory)
        jquery-ui.css
```